# Android: ContextMenu not displaying

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

In my application, I have a ListView in my main layout. In the corresponding Activity, I have the following in my onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    app = (MyTallyKeeperApplication) getApplication();
    adapter = new TallyItemListAdapter(this, app.getTallyItems());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

Each item in the ListView is of type TallyItemView, inheriting from LinearLayout. The code I used to inflate the context menu is:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.i(MyTallyKeeperMain.class.getSimpleName(), "onCreateContextMenu");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.item_menu, menu);
}
```

In theory, when you long press on an item, you are shown a context menu which gives you options to edit that item or delete it. But when I long press on an item, nothing is shown.
Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens if the list has focusable items (checkbox etc.) In the layout of the list row include this for the focusable components.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: what if we need them to be focusable?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your `super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);` last rather than first. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Inflation) showing the use of a context menu with a `ListView`.

Comment: I tried moving it, but no luck. Does the use of a compound control have anything to do with this?

Comment: For some reason onCreateContextMenu doesn't seem to be called. I am certain of this because the logging statement I put in there isn't showing up in LogCat.

Comment: I did a little more digging around my code and I found that the context menu is not being properly registered for the listview. The ListView I put in main.xml has an ID of @android:id/list. Using registerForContextMenu(getListView()) should have worked. I don't get it.